# How can I find the oldest SMS that is stored on my phone?

Tags: sms, oneplus6t

How can I find the oldest SMS that is stored on my phone?

Since SMSs are threaded I can't just scroll all the way down to find my oldest message.

The reason I want to do this is that I use a backup solution for SMS that, for unknown reasons, has failed to copy some messages from my current phone. I therefore want to startover and make a full backup of my current phine. At the same time I have a decade worth of history backed up in this solution and I just want to cull the messages that is on my current phone.

Basically, in my backup solution I have messages 1 to 1200. 1 to 1000 are old, from old phones, while 1001 to 1200 are on my current phone. I want to find 1001 and then delete all messages newer than that from the backup. Finally I will backup 1001 and newer again.

Android 10 on a Oneplus 6T